# Using check box to enable call drag

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm simply trying to call the drag function if the checbox has been ticked. I have been trying to implement the following examples:

## 1

```
node.call(function(d) { if d3.selectAll("input").property("checked", true) {return drag } })
```

## 2

```
d3.selectAll("input").on("change", change);

      
    function change() {

 if (this.value === true )  da();



       function da() {

      node.call(drag);

       }
```

It doesnt show an error, just doesnt drag after it is checked - http://jsfiddle.net/gUF8x/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem there is that `this.value` is set to the value of the checkbox, not to the state (e.g. it doesn't become true or false based on if the checkbox is checked). Instead, you should use `this.checked`:

```
if (this.checked === true )  da();
```

That will allow the call to `da();` to happen, however you will then get an error, because as it is currently written, the `da()` function is not in the global scope (it is currently a child of the `draw()` function), so to achieve what you are looking for will require more modifications to the code and structure. At least you'll have errors to use from here forward though...

Comment: I'm not all that experienced in d3.js, but I would assume that you basically want to return all values to their original state. That could mean resetting them to zero, or it might mean setting them to the negatives of what you set previously.

Comment: thanks, for your help. I found a solution: else if (this.checked == false ) { return node.call(dragno); };    
        var dragno = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(Object)
  .on("drag", null);